# how to open AD FS Sign-in Pages?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, adfs

I am trying to customize ADFS sign in page using poweshell command using article given in following link.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx

But I am not able to get how to open sign on page, How to open AD FS Sign-in Pages ?

Thanks In Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can open ADFS sign on page from following way ...

https://testadfs.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx  (need to change "testadfs.com" to your server name)